# Conditional that checks if a current category has any subcategory with posts

Tags: posts, categories

I'm looking for a way to make a conditional rule that checks, in a category archive template, if the current category has any subcategories with posts.

More specifically, the posts are "products" in a Woocommerce setup.

So far I was only able to check if the current category has subcategories with the code below. But even after some searching I wasn't able to advance any further.

```
$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
'parent'    => $term->term_id,
'hide_empty' => false
) );
if($children) {
    echo 'something';
}
```

Comment: what is left is to check if those categories have posts right?

Comment: @DavidLee Yes! 
Although I don't know if it's possible with this piece of code.

Comment: Please check this... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176317/check-if-current-category-has-subcategories/192470

Answer (score 0):

Please set **hide_empty** to **true** which will fetch only categories which is assigned to post.

```
$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( 'category', array(
'parent' => $term->term_id,
'hide_empty' => true
) );
```

Comment: Oh I see, but I don't want to hide empty categories.
I'm sorry if it wasn't explicit, but what I want to do is add some html to a category page if that same category page has at least one subcategory with posts.